# How to fetch large dataset to the array from Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance

I have a collection of 150.000 elements. It is less then 150MB in size. 
For testing reasons I want to put it to the array. This is relatively small amount of data so I expect it should be done without any problems. Not so.

My previous edit was about distinction between shell and NodeJS, but I do not think this is the point now, so I edited post to represent more interesting question.

Rig: My driver version is 3, Mongo version is 3.6. I use latest NodeJS as main tool. 8GB RAM.

So, there are two basic ways of getting collection items to an array.

**Testing script (using moment)**

```
exports.testMongoLoad = function() {
  console.log("started");
  var m1 = moment();
  testMongoLoad2(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var m2 = moment();
    console.log(
      "Returned " +
        docs.length +
        " documents in " +
        m2.diff(m1, "ms") +
        " ms as array"
    );
  });
};
```

**toArray() function**

```
testMongoLoad1 = function(callback) {
  db
        .get()
        .collection("matchesn")
        .find({})
        .toArray(function(err, docs) {
          if (err) return callback(err);
          return callback(null, docs);
        });
    };
```

*~ 8 seconds*

**each() function**

```
testMongoLoad2 = function(callback) {
  docs = [];
  db
    .get()
    .collection("matchesn")
    .find({})
    //.project({ _id: 1 })
    .each(function(err, doc) {
      if (doc) {
        docs.push(doc);
      } else {
        return callback(null, docs);
      }
    });
};
```

*~ 8 seconds*

If I use `project` I get results in *~ 1 second*.

If I just populate some array with 150000 elements (see my comment), it finish in *~ 60 ms*

So, what is the right way? Can it be done, or there is 100% ban on driver level for such actions?

UPD

Basically `toArray` implementation is doing `next` until there is nothing 
[toArray source code](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2c35d76f08574225b8db02d7bef687123e6bb018/lib/cursor.js)

```
var toArray = function(self, callback) {
  var items = [];

  // Reset cursor
  self.rewind();
  self.s.state = Cursor.INIT;

  // Fetch all the documents
  var fetchDocs = function() {
    self._next(function(err, doc) {
      if (err) return handleCallback(callback, err);
      if (doc == null) {
        return self.close({ skipKillCursors: true }, () => handleCallback(callback, null, items));
      }

      // Add doc to items
      items.push(doc);

      // Get all buffered objects
      if (self.bufferedCount() > 0) {
        var docs = self.readBufferedDocuments(self.bufferedCount());

        // Transform the doc if transform method added
        if (self.s.transforms && typeof self.s.transforms.doc === 'function') {
          docs = docs.map(self.s.transforms.doc);
        }

        push.apply(items, docs);
      }

      // Attempt a fetch
      fetchDocs();
    });
  };

  fetchDocs();
};
```

Comment: Using `project` to strip returned documents from everything except `_id` allowed to top up the speed to 1144 ms. Can it be, that the problem is not with mongo or mongo driver? Something with 150MB array to RAM in node? It should not be.

Comment: Nope. Created (in for loop) an array (with length 150000) of slightly randomized  element from the collection - 60ms. I am pretty lost. Seems that using drivers "next" 1500 000 is the culpit, yet I can not point a finger at it, and I can not find any information on how to do it (get a lot millions of documents, for statistics, for example) right.

Comment: Are you running both mongoshell and nodejs with identical infrastructure (same network path traversed)? To measure the speed you take the timestamp immediatelly before and then after the operation and then calculate the difference (make sure you make the second measurement after the quuery is run (synchronous/blocking)) - also, can you paste any code to play around with and observe what you are doing?

Comment: I am running both on local machine (8GB RAM), so infrastructure is basically the same. I try to create timestamps to immediately before and after the operation, but that is not the point. The difference is seen with naked eye (e.g. seconds vs milliseconds). I will update the post.

Comment: Are there any other differences in the code? Can you run the `.explain();` like here to see if an index is used in one case and not on the other? Example of explain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745630/very-slow-performance-on-mongodb-find

Comment: Index is not used in both cases :) The query is the same with   "winningPlan" : {
   "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
   "direction" : "forward"
  }, 
 For now the only thing I understood that toArray and each for all docs are working exactly the same.

Comment: To be clear - query works very fast (as it should be). Problem is with accessing data from cursor.